# Parse query in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

[image]Irrespective of object ids,I want to retrieve all the data in a column. I have 10 usernames and all their game scores. I want to get all the usernames and corresponding game scores .What should be my query ? I have stored the usernames as well in the class.I want it in swift. TIA :)

```
var messages = [String]()
var usernames = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFQuery(className: "RescuePost")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    self.messages.append(object["message"] as! String)
                    self.usernames.append(object["username"] as! String)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post a picture of your parse class that you want to query

Comment: done :) i want to get all usernames and all messages. TIA :)

Comment: i want - 'aaaa'  and 'hello#mylapore', 'partha' and  'hi' , 'lamar' and 'merry christmas'..like this..i want the username and their message

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download all those info you will need somewhere to put it , therefore let's create a data structure using the `struct`

```
 struct myDataStructure {
        var username:String?
        var userId:String?
        var message:String?
        var Userlocation:PFGeoPoint?
    }
```

Now let's create an `array of that struct`

```
var arrayOfData = [myDataStructure]()
```

Your query will look like that :

```
 func queryData()
    {
       let query = PFQuery(className: "NameOfClassYouWantToQueryFrom")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects :[PFObject]?, error :NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                if let objects = objects
                {
                    for eachSingleUser in objects
                    {
                        let username = eachSingleUser["username"] as! String
                        let userId = eachSingleUser["userId"] as! String
                        let message = eachSingleUser["message"] as? String
                        let userLocation = eachSingleUser["location"] as? PFGeoPoint

                          var singleData = myDataStructure()
                           singleData.username = username
                           singleData.userId = userId
                           singleData.message = message
                           singleData.Userlocation = userLocation

                           self.arrayOfData.append(singleData)    
                          //<----- Since you are using UITableView don't forget to reload data
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Some Explanation:

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` method is a method that returns all your data or objects from parse into an array of PFObjects. Therefore our job is to check and extract those data in order to use it :)

```
       let username = eachSingleUser["username"] as! String
```

In this line above, `eachSingleUser` is one of the many objects from parse that contains all your fields such as username, userId, message, therefore by using the subscript `eachSingleUser[""]` we will be able to access all those fields.

Finally :

```
   self.arrayOfData.append(singleData)
```

In this line above we are saving each single objects into the array.

All your data is being saved and can be accessed in that array.

**In cellPathRowAtIndexPath()**

```
let data = arrayofData[indexPath.row]
 cell.textlabel.text = data.username
 cell.detailTextlabel.text = data.message
```

Comment: how do i access individual data from this array? i am a little poor at structures data type  :(

Comment: How would access each data into a regular array ?

Comment: Nope , username is a string type not a UILabel. Therefore the username.text is only for UILabel... How would you access each data into a regular array .. Google it

Comment: indexpath.row is because i want to use it as a part of table :)

Comment: Still wrong :) username is not the array, username is a field in the array

Comment: look at  my edit answer again you will find your answer there.

Comment: check my edits and let me know if i could do it this way

Comment: No your messages variable is type string not array... I gave your the answer

Comment: i have declared it as an array of strings only :) and its working :) thanks a lot :) i used your query format to solve :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to get ALL objects of a class. You do this easily by constructing a [basic query](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-basic-queries) with no constraints, meaning your query will match with all records.

In your tableview, you access the values normally for each object:

```
object.objectForKey("username")
```

Comment: check my edits and let me know if that is correct :)

Comment: @ParthasaarathySudarsan Yes, that's it :-)

Comment: Be aware, though, of the 1000 object max limit from Parse queries

Comment: Any query against the Parse backend will at most return 1000 objects. There should never be a reason for you to fetch more than that (or even close to that). If you need to do something with that many objects, you should do it in cloud code; not on the device.